# Choose between two input in gstreamer plugin

Tags: c, plugins, input, gstreamer

I am currently writing a Gstreamer-1.0 plugin with an `audio/x-raw` source.

I would like to send to my plugin two input source. One would be de default source and the other one would be use if a condition is true like this :

```
       ____________________________________
      |                                    |
   ->-|      default source                |-->---
  |   |____________________________________|      |           _______________
  |                                               |          |               |
t-|                                               |----->----|   my plugin   |
  |    ____________________________________       |          |_______________|
  |   |                                    |      |
   ->-|      secondary source              |-->---
      |____________________________________|
```

A good way of doing this seems to be by using an `input selector` but I don't 
 know how to use it. Does anyone know how to add and tune an `input selector`?

Comment: Go the below at this link: http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Switching-between-videos-with-input-selector-td2328618.html, you have a code python exemple that use input-selector (SwitchVideoSound.py)

Comment: Tank you very much! I will carefully look at this link and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `input-selector` element is the right choice for this.

There is a full example of using it in the tests included with the [`gst-plugins-base`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-plugins-base.html) package.

Build it by running `.autogen.sh` followed by `make` (you may need to install some dependencies).

The source and the executable of the `input-selector` example are here:

```
tests/icles/input-selector-test.c
./tests/icles/input-selector-test
```